# Outsourcing the delegate and datasource of a picker to another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uipickerview

I am creating more than one picker in one view controller, so I have to use separate cocoa touch classes to handle the datasource and delegate methods of each of them. I have this code:

```
myPicker.delegate = CustomPickerViewController

myPicker.dataSource = CustomPickerViewController
```

In this case, `CustomPickerViewController` is a cocoa touch class in a separate file which has the required `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`methods implemented. So, what should I be assigning to the above properties in order to handle populating a picker view using the CustomPickerViewController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each picker should get its own instance of `CustomPickerViewController`.

```
myPicker.delegate = CustomPickerViewController()
myPicker.dataSource = myPicker.delegate

anotherPicker.delegate = CustomPickerViewController()
anotherPicker.dataSource = anotherPicker.delegate
```